Expanding a 1S 18650 battery
I have a battery with 3 Li-ion cells in parallel and a 1S protectors BMS. I wish to add 6 more Li-ion cells in parallel with it. Can just add the cells? Or do I also need to add any other component to the expanded battery?


Are the batteries in series or parallel? How you intended to "just" wire it?

The need is of course for adding battery in parallel and right now they are in parallel as well. Thank you for the time being.

I'm reopening this question. It has two good answers. I can understand what is wanted. The photo does a good job of confirming what the text says. I don't understand why the closers did not consider tere was enough informatio - maybe it was closed before David Andreas edit.

@intercettazioni   Note that the BMS balancing current is is usually small compared to cell capacity. It will be smaller again proportionately with 3 x as many cells. As there is only one cell this is less important as it does not attempt to balance between cells - but depending on design MAY attempt to bleed current off if Vbat starts to exceed Vbat max. It will not do a good job of holding Vmax under 4.2x vots - but it will cutout completely just as well for too high pr too low battery voltage. ...

...  Note also that the BMS pass transistor needs to handle the current from all cells. IF you intend to draw more current be sure that the pass transistor is rated accordingly.

@RussellMcMahon With a 1S BMS, there is no balancing as all cells are in parallel. Size of pass transistor is only an issue if loads or charge rate are changed from the original setup.

@SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica Yes/No :-). I thought about not saying that BUT it deepends on the designer. It may well not usually be done but the same action that is taken with N cells when one starts to go overvotage still has some legitimacy with one. If during the tail of CV charging the cell rises above a deemed safe level a BMS COULD start to sihon off current. This woud be prefereable to just hitting the Vabsmax level and turning off the pass FET. It MAY save full disconect. Do people do this? Usually not. Am I complicating things by adding it? Probably.

@SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica  I agree re pass transistor sizing.We do not know if tripling the cells is to get more runtime, or more current, or some mix. Hence my "...  IF you intend to draw more current ... ".

Yes, you may add mode cells in parallel with the other cells in your 1S battery without modifying the protector BMS.
Just make sure that the cells you're adding are at the same voltage as the present ones. If you don't, damaging currents with flow between the cells.
Note: you are adding "cells", not "batteries". You have a single battery that contains 3 cells and will contain 9 cells. (In italiano: "nove celle in una batteria".)

Thanks a lot Sir.

You can add, however you must be extremely careful when connecting the new cells. If they are charged to a different voltage from the original ones, then once connected, a very large equalizing current will flow; possibly damaging the cells.
Measure the voltage of the new cell, and either charge or discharge the original pack to the same value. You should try to get these as close as possible; a 0.1 V difference will lead to currents of about 1 A. This is probably safe, but larger imbalances may not be.

Thank you very much.
